# Can an external agent do work on an isolated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

We know that an isolated system can't exchange any kind of energy. But if any external agent does work on the isolated system then the internal energy the of the system will increase, that is the energy of that agent is getting transferred to the internal energy of the system, but it's defying the defination that energy can't be exchanged . So can an external agent do work on an isolated system?

Comment: But if it's an isolated system, then there can't be any influence from any external agent. Otherwise we wouldn't call is isolated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please consider writing descriptive question titles with appropriate punctuation, grammar, and formatting. See this meta post: [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413). I've edited it here.

Answer (score 4):

No. That goes against the definition of an [isolated system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_system). Such a system cannot interact with anything other than itself. If an external agent does work on the system, it is no longer isolated. However, if we define a new system, which consists of the original system and the agent, this new system can be said to be isolated if there are no other agents.